# Highchart: Line at bottom-border appear

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I made a highchart and now have a problem. When I zoom, the YAxis-Gridline is out of the border and the border-bottom-line is thicker than before. 
Is there a option, which I configured wrong or why does this Line on the bottom appear and the gridline is over the border?
I tried to set `lineWidth: 0`, but didnt change anything

See this jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jFG77/)
After a zoom the problem appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known bug, which is reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2964)

Comment: Unfortuantely you need to stay on track with the github thread.